# Problema con variable en Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ví que poniendo un guión el nombre de la variable y el valor se debe imprimir en pantalla cuando pongas el nombre en un párrafo pero pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica que no tengas espacios al inicio de la línea; por ejemplo, esta línea marca error:

```
 - nombre = "Ernesto"
```

Pero esta línea no:

```
- nombre = "Ernesto"
```

Comment: nota: el guión al inicio de línea ejecuta código ruby, este código se evalúa pero no se inserta en el doc (a menos que sea asignar valor a una variable y la uses después) http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running-ruby--